Encoding data changes model output?
I am experimenting with a simple MLPClassifier and one-hot encoding in SKLearn.
data = pd.read_csv("./Synthetic_data.csv", header=0)
filtered_data = data.drop(['diag_binary'], axis=1)

X = filtered_data[['sex', 'age', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q']]
y = filtered_data[['diag_multi']]

datasets = train_test_split(X_1hot, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42, stratify=y)
train_data, test_data, train_labels, test_labels = datasets

enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
train_data = enc.fit_transform(train_data)
test_data = enc.transform(test_data)

mlp = MLPClassifier(max_iter=1000, batch_size=32, random_state=42)
mlp.fit(train_data, train_labels.values.ravel())
print(mlp.score(test_data, test_labels))

The score of my MLP in this setup is higher compared to the MLP without one-hot encoded data. I do not understand as to how the encoding can change the output of my model?
To provide context to the database: The features 'a' to 'z' all represent questions from a survey with 4 possible values: 'yes', 'no', 'don't know' and 'skipped' and are encoded with 1,2,3 and 9. Since the MLP could learn an ordinal relation between the samples I one-hot encode these values. I also one-hot encode 'sex' since similar to the other features it is also encoded as 1,2 and 3. Same for 'age' of course, even though I am not sure if one-hot encoding is the correct way to handle the age values. The dataset is very imbalanced so this may be a problem, I'm not sure.

I find encoding the target using one-hot encoding a very uncommon approach. secondly, I am not familiar with MLPClassifier, however, I do know that encoding and its type do impact performance negatively/or positively, check if you need to change the type of encoding for some features in X, and test the removal of target variable encoding or change the type of encoder. in simple words, high dimensional data could cause an overfitted model or it could help find the sweet spot and a good model.

Ok, I did not know that encoding could have that kind of impact. In my case it seems like the higher dimensional data improves my model, but I'm not sure I understand how a different representation of the same data changes performance.
I cleaned up my question, only one-hot encoding train and test data now and also doing that after the split, but still facing the same problem. Maybe the fact some age values are represented very little is a problem since one-hot encoding creates columns that are filled was almost only zeros?

Applying an encoding could increase your model's performance, or it could introduce noise to the point that the model won't be able to classify properly.
Applying One-hot encoding to your features will remove any ordinal relationship in their values (if you have an ordinal relationship in some features please apply an ordinal encoder).
In addition, if you have a specific category feature that has an imbalanced representation in your data (e.x. a feature called type_business has the value "Logistics" in more than 40% of your data, it is clear that it is a dominant category in this feature, the model might give more importance to this category without you knowing, so one hot encoding will prevent that).
I don't know about MLP, but some models perform better on numeric data like logistic regression, therefore encoding will be a good idea.
I am unsure why you encode the feature "age", just keep it numerical and ordinal.

NOTE: since you have imbalanced data, it is recommended to use precision and recall (or AUC_Precision recall curve) to measure your model's performance.


NOTE2: Usually we do the encoding before the train_test split, why? because if there is a category that exists in test, but not in train, your enc.transform() will crash since it doesn't know how to encode this new category, the handle_unknown will ignore these cases, but if you have a small dataset, that will reduce its size.

I hope this helps!

Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure what you mean in your third paragraph starting with "In addition, ...", could you clarify that? Regarding the encoding, I do it after the train/test split because I want to avoid test data leakage. The case you described in Note 2 actually happened to me, I have a category in test, that is not in the train set so I have a column less. But as I understand it, this should be the intended way of handling this, since the model has to work only with the train set, so any extra columns created by test data leakage should not be desired.

Let's assume you have a categorical column called type_of_business, and in your training sample, 40% of your data has the value 'logistics'. The classification model might be biased towards this category since it represents the majority and gives it more importance than it should be. To eliminate that, you could use one-hot encoding since it expands the dimensionality and reduces this probable natural bias.
Regarding encoding before/after split,what you did is considered clean,although there isn't much proof of data leakage(I agree with https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/78148/154433).
